# How long until the earth is covered in pumpkin vines?

Tags: arithmetic

There are 500 seeds in an average pumpkin.
It takes 20 weeks to produce a vine with 1 pumpkin from a seed and then the vine withers.
A live vine covers 2 square meters of land.
The earths diameter is 12,742 km and its surface is 33% land.

I'm a diabolical psychopath and I have managed to obtain 1 pumpkin seed! How long will it take me to cover all land mass with pumpkin vines?

Comment: What diabolical effort can you display for this task?

Comment: Assume infinite efficiency given the parameters stated. All 500 seeds are instantly planted into fertile soil. I'm very good at farming and my crops always grow.

Comment: Where did you get your (purported) facts about pumpkin biology from? Are you supposing that you can get _every_ seed to grow into a fertile pumpkin plant? How are you going to keep the owners of the land you're cultivating pumpkins on from weeding your plants away before they bear fruit, once you have so many that your own back yard is too small for all of them?

Comment: Also, consider that not all of the earth's land is arable -- and even for the part of it that is, you'll have to spend a considerable effort clearing it of existing vegetation, which is bound to attract the unfavorable attention of local landowners and/or authorities. Being a single person, no matter how diabolical and psychopathic, will severely hamper your ability to overcome these limits.

Comment: Did you see War of the Worlds? The Martians pulverised humans and used their remains to fertilise their vegetation. Remember, I'm very diabolical!

Comment: @LorryLaurencemcLarry: I think you're horribly overestimating the degree to which the sincerity of someone's ill intent can make up for their lack of resources.

Comment: This is a math forum, NOT a science forum! It's an arithmetical question that should be solvable using basic algebra.

Comment: @LorryLaurencemcLarry Actually, this is a math question and answer site, not a math forum.  Any discussion here is best aimed at clarifying the questions and answers, and should result in edits to the questions and answers.  The discussion itself is ancillary.  (Having said that, I do appreciate, and enjoy, that some people are not afraid to be colorful with what they write.)

Comment: one answer results in 123 weeks and the other 106 weeks. Those are very different answers. Why?

Comment: We really only differ by one cycle. The question is when do we have a vine, once we have a seed or once we have a pumpkin. I decided for the latter.

Comment: Good point! I updated the question to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about weeks and seeds, pumpkins and vine covered area, we come up with
\begin{align}
p(0) &= (1, 0, 0) \\
p(20) &= (500, 1, 2) \\
p(40) &= (500^2, 500, 1000)
\end{align}
then we laugh madly, BWAHAHAHAHHHAHAA, and note
$$
p(20 k) = (500^k, 500^{k-1}, 2 \cdot 500^{k-1}) \quad (k \ge 1)
$$
The feasible area is
$$
A = p \, 4\pi r^2 = p \, 4 \pi (d/2)^2 = p \pi d^2 = 2 \cdot 500^{k-1}
$$
Taking a logarithm gives:
$$
\ln(p\pi d^2) = \ln(2) + (k-1) \ln(500) \Rightarrow \\
k = 1 + \frac{\ln(p\pi d^2) - \ln(2)}{\ln(500)}
= 6.159415997965432
$$
$20$ weeks, where $p = 33 \%$ and $d = 12742000$m.

So we need $7$ cycles of $20$ weeks of mad fun.

Comment: So 123.18831995930864 weeks, or 140 if your round up to the end of the last harvest.

Comment: The other guy got 106.76 weeks. Where did you two differ?

Comment: A slight difference is $p=0.33$ vs $1/3$.

Answer (score 2):

We can find the surface area of the earth $$SA = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^2=\frac{4}{3}\pi (\frac{12,742}{2}km)^2=\frac{4}{3}\pi (6371km)^2=\frac{4}{3}\pi (6371000m)^2$$ Scaled to $\frac{1}{3}$ (Assuming $33\% = \frac{1}{3}$) $$SA=4\pi(6371000)^2$$ Knowing each plant takes $2m^2$ of land, we will need $$Plants = \frac{SA}{2}=2\pi(6371000)^2$$ We will get pumpkin seeds at a rate of $$Seeds = (500)^{n}$$ where $n=20 \text{ weeks}$.Therefore we need to solve $2\pi(6371000)^2=500^n$ for $n$. $$2\pi(6371000)^2=500^n \\ \log(2\pi(6371000)^2)=\log(500^n) \\ \log(2\pi(6371000)^2)=n\log(500) \\ n= \frac{\log(2\pi(6371000)^2)}{\log(500)} \\ n \approx 5.34$$ Note that $n$ is in units of $\frac{1}{20 \text{ weeks}}$ so $$n \approx 106.76 \text{ weeks} \\ n \approx 747.29 \text{ days}$$